# Excel Filter Numbers ending in zero

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel column which is formatted as a number with one decimal place.
I want to filter only the numberd which end in 0.
1.0
2.0
40.0

When i filter manually using Number ends with 0 - it filters out everything.
When i use the following code i get the same (although im using multi criteria).
Excel 2016.

```
Sub ImmediateMain()

With ActiveSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
With ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$T$200")
        .AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Immediate"
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="*0"
End With
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this as an option to the issue.

Add a column to your data and add the below formula for all rows, you could then filter on the result of the formula: -

`=IF(ISERR(FIND(".",A1,1)),"Whole","Not whole")`

When you store `1.0` in a cell, only `1` is stored, they mean the same thing, but Excel will format it to look like `1.0` if requested (i.e. Show to *N* decimal places).

The above used `find` to see if there is a decimal point, if there is not an error is thrown so `iserr` is used, if there is an error, there was no decimal point.

NOTE: You may want to subsequently copy the new column and paste over itself as 'paste special' > 'values' to make filtering easier.

Answer (score 1):

You could add another column (column B), with a formula referencing your existing column (column A):

```
=A1-floor(A1)
```

You would then filter the column B where the value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

click on the dropdown, under number filter, in the search box type `"*.0"` then press enter. That is 1 solution

Answer (score 0):

Apply Conditional Formatting to your data:

Type: Formula based, Formula: `=IF(A2=INT(A2))` Formatting: e.g. Yellow Interior Color

And Filter based on Interior Color.